# How to query history of the balances

Tags: nearprotocol

For various use cases it's valuable to display historical data of the balance on some account.

What is the best way to query this data from NEAR protocol?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? Struggling with this right now, can't connect to the indexer, it says available connection slots are full...

Answer (score 0):

You'll get the account transaction history from this url:

`https://helper.mainnet.near.org/account/<ACCOUNT_NAME>/activity?offset=<TIME_STAMP_NANOS>&limit=<NUMBER_OF_TRANSACTIONS>`

Use the block timestamp of the latest transaction in the result to ask for the previous chunk of transactions (given you set the limit to a number that doesn't include all the trasaction). when you've found the initial transaction. Accumulate deposit (look at the signer_id to determine direction) and gas amounts to get the balance after each transaction.